# Change class of iframe element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, iframe

I have an iframe (soundcloud embedded track) of a particular class.
What I want is that, when I click on the iframe, its class change to another one with different properties.

My code for that is:
index.html

```
<script src="javascripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe class="soundcloud" id="soundcloudtrack" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/123888618&amp;color=00ffc6&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=true&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_artwork=false&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe>

<script>
  $('#soundcloudtrack').click(
     function (v) {
       $(this).toggleClass('soundcloud soundcloudext');
       /*document.getElementById("soundcloudtrack").className = "soundcloudext";*/
     }
  );
</script>
```

and style.css:

```
.soundcloud{
    z-index:99997;
    width:100%;
    height:62px;
    opacity:0.25;
}

.soundcloudext{
    z-index:99997;
    width:100%;
    height:135px;
    opacity:1;
  }
```

But it's not working and I can't see why. I have also tried with getElementById. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really target the iframe directly as I.G stated, you need to set something over the iframe that you can control on your webpage , I wrote something on jsfiddle, please try and see if it's what you are looking for:    https://jsfiddle.net/652ejv6j/#run.

```
<div id="player">
  <span>click here</span>
  <iframe class="soundcloud" id="soundcloudtrack" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/123888618&amp;color=00ffc6&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=true&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_artwork=false&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe>

</div>



 $('#player span').click(function() {
 //alert(1);
 $("#soundcloudtrack").toggleClass('soundcloud soundcloudext');
    alert($("#soundcloudtrack").attr("class"));
  /*document.getElementById("soundcloudtrack").className = "soundcloudext";*/
});

.soundcloud {
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 62px;
  opacity: 0.25;
}

.soundcloudext {
  z-index: 99997;
  width: 100%;
  height: 135px;
  opacity: 1;
}

#player {
  position: relaitve;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#player span {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  top: 40px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

ALT Check if there's an API for your player through which you can control directly.

Comment: Thank you for your first solution! Meanwhile, following your advice I have found info about Soundcloud API, but I'm not sure whether I should use this page (https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget) or this one (https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/html5-widget-api). I am trying without any success. Could you please tell me how you would use this info to handle the iframe ".click()" event?
If this is going off-topic I'll text you in private!

Comment: Well, yes that's what you should checkout. But still, you wold not to formulate some "manipulation" around mimicking the "iframe click" event, you cannot handle that, in other words the iframe is a way to serve you the player from SoundCloud, it isn't something that you have full control over. So one of the thing, depending on what you want to do exactly, is to track a PLAY/PAUSE event and act upon those assuming the user would have clicked on the player.